# spring boot thymeleaf project not running as war in external tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, web-applications, war

I've developed project in Spring Boot Thymeleaf. When I packaging as war, it seems all good, but when I run it on Tomcat it doesn't start.

First, I added in pom as

```xml
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

Second, I changed my main class to extend `SpringBootServletInitializer`.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class MedleaperApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MedleaperApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override 
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) { return
      application.sources(MedleaperApplication.class); // Replace DemoApplication
    }
}
```

Third, I added this dependency to `pom.xml`

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

After then I:

1. ran `mvn clean` and `mvn clean install`
2. depolyed war to Tomcat webapp folder
3. ran `startup.bat` command to start Tomcat

However, Tomcat started it didn't execute my application.

How to deploy a Spring Boot project on Tomcat as war or jar?